# Swap alt and ctrl in certain programs on Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard-layout

I would like to swap alt and ctrl key when launching certain programs on Linux, such as zsh and emacs, while keep the original keyboard layout when using other programs. Is it possible to do so?

EDIT:

One possible solution might be able to be derived from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension#Multiple_layouts), but it doesn't talk about how to change the modifier.

Comment: I ever wondering how to do this for Emacs and came across https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/application-specific-keymapping . Note that I did not try this but went to Evil.

Comment: @TobySpeight updated.